# Can MLFlow be used without the `with mlflow.start_run()` block?

Tags: python, machine-learning, mlflow, mlops

I want to track an entire notebook and log the parameters of cleaning steps that occur before training a model. I'd like to use [`mlflow`](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/index.html) to do it, but on all the docs it looks like you have to track models using this format:

```
with mlflow.start_run():
    ...
```

Is there a way to track an entire notebook using mlflow without the `with` block?

Comment: `with` just allows `mlflow` a chance to clean up when the `with` block exits. In a notebook you could do without it.

Comment: How does that work? I can't find any documentation on how to switch it on and off without the with block. Could you add an answer for that, I'll happily accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to start and end an `mlflow` run without the context manager syntax.

To do this you can simply write:

```
mflow.start_run()
...
your_run_code_here
...
mlflow.end_run()
```

You can read more about it in the [mlflow documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html).

Comment: Note that technically the call `end_run()` could be omitted if it's at the end of the script. MLflow registers an `atexit` handler that automatically calls `end_run()`, see here in the [code](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/505a75a1b8267d25cea09db6f0bfff16112bbe66/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py#L467) (although admittedly, that might be considered an implementation detail).